Terraform catchpoint 400 bad request
resource "ssl_test" "chopper"{
  test_name     = "test"
  provider      = catchpoint
  division_id   = 100
  product_id    = 200
  folder_id     = 300
  monitor       = "ssl"
  test_location = "www.google.com"
  end_time      = "2024-10-30T04:59:00Z"
}

I am trying to create catchpoint ssl test here.
terraform init and plan working fine.
When I tried to apply using terraform apply cmd it is failing with below error:
ssl_test.chopper: Creating...
│ 
**Error: 400 bad request**
│ 
│   with ssl_test.chopper,
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "ssl_test" "chopper":
│   14: resource "ssl_test" "chopper"{`


This error is being returned by the remote API that this provider is communicating with, and not by the provider itself or by Terraform. Therefore I would recommend contacting the vendor for help with this, because "Bad Request" is too generic an error message to debug without access to the source code of the server that's returning it.

@MartinAtkins Thanks! I checked with my API token provider and they have added my IP with that API. As per he, it should work but it is still not working. I am still not getting if he added the IP and my configuration is also valid then what is the problem here?
